# Why set datetime format for jackson not works

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jackson

spring boot version: 2.7.8

I want to set a global format for all `java.util.Date` and date time types in `java.time.*`

what I have tried:

setting in application.yml:

```
app:
  dateFormat: "yyyy/MM/dd"
  timeFormat: "HH:mm:ss"

spring
  jackson:
    date-format: "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"
```

this is not working, all date types is still formatted as long.

```java
@Configuration
public class JacksonConfig {
    @Value("${app.dateFormat}")
    private String dateFormat;
    
    @Value("${app.dateFormat} ${app.timeFormat}")
    private String dateTimeFormat;
    
    
    @Bean
    public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer jsonCustomizer() {
       System.out.println("---------------");
        return builder -> {
            builder.simpleDateFormat(dateFormat);
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateFormat)));
            builder.serializers(new LocalDateTimeSerializer(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(dateTimeFormat)));
        };
    }
}
```

this is not working too, all date types is still formatted as long. but the `System.out.println("---------------")` is executed, so it's picked up by spring.

I have another configuration class, which config jackson to ignore null properties, if that matters.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    
    @Override
    public void extendMessageConverters(List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {
        converters.forEach(c -> {
            if(c instanceof MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter) {
                MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter jc = (MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter)c;
                jc.getObjectMapper().setSerializationInclusion(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL);
            }
        });
        WebMvcConfigurer.super.extendMessageConverters(converters);
    }

}
```

please give me some hint.

Comment: As per this article https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates, its mentioned "Unfortunately, it doesn't work with the Java 8 date types, such as LocalDate and LocalDateTime. We can only use it to format fields of the type java.util.Date or the java.util.Calendar"

Comment: it's the @EnableWebMVC preventing jackson configuration works....

Comment: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype/jackson-datatype-jsr310

Comment: Remove the `@EnableWebMvc` as that disables auto configuration of the web and jackson parts. Even better ditch the whole class and just add `spring.jackson.default-property-inclusion=NON_NULL` which achieves the same.